# Is it possible to call a shell script from within a CodeIgniter Controller?

Tags: php, shell, codeigniter

I have a shell script written that will use LibreOffice to convert a docx file to a pdf.  That works fine.  What I am trying to do is to somehow call this shell script from with my CodeIgniter controller, so that it will run each time the controller is called.

Currently, I have tried:

My shell script "convert_to_pdf":

```
cd /applications/libreoffice.app/contents/macos
./soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /applications/mamp/htdocs/convert /applications/mamp/htdocs/convert/testDoc.docx
```

My controller contains this, which I tried to use to run the shell script:

```
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/convert_to_pdf");
```

I'm new to all of this, so I am not even sure that this is possible.  I know the shell script works when I run it from the terminal, but I can't get it to be used in the controller.  Any ideas?

Thanks for the help ahead of time!

**EDIT**

I did get this working by using the following in my controller:

```
exec('cd /applications/libreoffice.app/contents/macos/ && ./soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /applications/mamp/htdocs/convert /applications/mamp/htdocs/convert/testDoc.docx', $output, $return);
```

However, I'm a little worried about security issues arising from this.  Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to check what's the output of that execution to try to see what's going on, and check if that helps.
[shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php)

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/convert_to_pdf');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Comment: I tried that just now, and there is nothing returned.  Just the tags.  I also ensured that shell_exec is enabled, so that's not it either.  Do you know if I'm using shell_exec correctly?

Comment: Does the `convert_to_pdf` script have the right permissions? Try 755